# How to test if a binding variable is null in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using ORDS to create a handler, and using PL/SQL to execute a script. The request should have in URL search params `id`.

When the `id` is supplied, everything works fine. But if the `id` is not supplied, I'd like to display a suitable error message.

Using `IF :id = null` or `IF :id = ''` doesn't seem to work. How should I do this properly?

Thanks!

Comment: :bind_variable IS NULL

Comment: NULL is a special thing in SQL. We cannot test for it using the equality operator. Instead we need to use the IS operator as @Pugzly shows above